# Camera2 API for Pixel 5 Zooming out below 1x

Tags: android, android-camera2, google-sites, google-pixel

In Google Pixel 5 default camera application, there is a feature that you can zoom out below 1x(By default: .6x, 1x, 2x).

Now is Camera2 framework, is there any function that apply the zoom-out functionality to get the wide angle of the picture?

I am in a situation that I need the wide angle of the camera, so that i can capture more content of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Pixel 5, see if the [CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO_RANGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO_RANGE) has a minimum below 1.0x, and if so, you can use [CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO) to zoom out.

This is a relatively new API to Android, so not all devices support a range <= 1.0x for accessing the wide-angle camera yet, but it's something that will be increasing over time.